How can we change the woocommerce single product slug for specific product categories?
I am trying to change the woocommerce single product slug for specific category, like as  default we have
home_url/product/sample-product
and i want to change this parent slug to something else, but for specific categories products.
home_url/trips/sample-product (in case of specific product category->"trips")
Trying these lines of code by using rewrite_rules
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_product_rewrite_rules');

   function custom_product_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
       // Add new rewrite rule to match the custom permalink structure
       $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
           '^trips/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?product=$matches[1]',
             // Rewrite rule for the new permalink structure
           '^trips/([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?product=$matches[2]',
             // Rewrite rule for product permalinks with IDs
           '^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?p=$matches[2]', 
             // Assuming this rule is still needed
           '^([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&product=$matches[3]'
       ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
   }

Do we have any better option?

The code you’ve provided is a good start, but it's not the most efficient way. Instead of rewriting the rules for every single product, you could use the post_type_link filter hook to modify the permalink structure for products in specific categories (trips).

Thanks @Richard, i used this filter hook and it worked.

I used this filter hook to modify the permalink structure for products in specific categories (trips).
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_product_permalink', 10, 3);

This filter hook can change the permalink structure for any specific product/post type or any category.
